# PostgreSQL - SQLSTATE[22007]

Tags: debian, postgresql, icecast

I have a box running Debian Wheezy, It is only used to operate Airtime (Icecast, LiquidSoap) It was working fine, after loading some more data into folders and editing `WATCHED FOLDERS`, I am getting an error.

```
SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 7 ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type time: "00:00:01."
LINE 1: ...:55:02.027392', '00:00:00.042608', '00:55:02.07', '00:00:01....
```

**postgresql-9.1-main.log**

```
2015-04-05 09:18:57 EDT ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type time: "00:00:01." at character 238
```

I have removed all data from the watched folders, I have tried to login into PostgreSQL and look at the data-base but get errors similar too.

```
postgres=# \d+ airtime
Did not find any relation named "airtime".
```

I have searched but can not find any where to start with this(only advanced discussion). Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like a bug in Airtime to me. Have you followed their documentation exactly? I vaguely remember them having some weird requirements. - If yes, consider filing a bug with them.

Comment: Yes I followed the documentation very closely, (it is necessary too).  I believe the install was fine, It has been running fine for 2 weeks.  I have searched there site. I did find one other report of the issue last year, but not remedy posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the problem. I edited a setting that deals with **Track Fade In**. In doing so from `0.50` to `1.` Leaving the `.` exposed at the end and bungling the database. Thank You

Comment: Congratulations, you've not only found a bug in Airtime, it's a **critical security bug** that appears to be usable for SQL injection attacks. It's important that you report this as soon as possible.